# stm32 ETH_IRQHandler never hit

Tags: stm32, ethernet, freertos, lwip

Im using stm32f746ZGT + LAN8472A  and lwip + freertos on my custom board. I generated default ethernet project by cubemx. I set static ip.

1. After connect the cable Link leds seem like good. Yellow one is
   stable and green one is blinky.
2. In debugging i can see netif is fully configured and link is up.
3. RXD0 and RXD1 pins which are entering mcu have signal (i can see on
   oscilloscope screen).
4. Clocks are good (i tested with oscilloscope).

But ETH_IRQHandler never hit so it doesnt answer any questions such as ping request. (I enabled ICMP at lwIP settings). What should i check to find the source of problem

Answer (score 0):

I'm stuck in an issue that seems quite similar to your. I don't have a solution yet, but thought to share something I found that maybe take you into the right direction.

What I've found is that this seems an issue of teh Micro itself. Following I'm signaling you two links that point to long disucssions regarding (I think) the same problem.

https://github.com/ARMmbed/mbed-os/issues/6262
[STM Errata](https://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/errata_sheet/group0/23/a6/11/0b/30/24/46/a5/DM00257543/files/DM00257543.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.DM00257543.pdf)

[STM Errata](https://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/errata_sheet/group0/23/a6/11/0b/30/24/46/a5/DM00257543/files/DM00257543.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.DM00257543.pdf)

They both seem to point out to a specific hardware vesion of the STM32F769 (Rev. A) and it seems that the thing is solved in Rev. Z......I use a lot of conditionals, I know, but until I'll be able to test a Micro with the correct revision I won't be able to confirm the problem/solution.

Hope it helps.

Lorenzo

**EDIT**!
While I don't have an answer yet I can confirm that on STM32F4, with the same software, the problem does not show.